# Prove that $\int _e^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{x^p} dx$ is divergent for $p \le1$.

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, alternative-proof

Prove that $\int _e^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{x^p} dx$ is divergent for $p \le1$.

So my textbook divides the problem into first case $p=1$ and integrates and cases $p<1$ in which it uses integration by parts. However, isn't my method also valid (and much faster)? It is:

$$\int _e^\infty \frac{1}{x^p} dx \le\int _e^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{x^p} dx$$

The integral on the left diverges by the so called $p$-series test for all $p \le 1$ and so does the integral on the right by the comparison test.

Comment: Your proof is fine for me, if you're supposed to know the result for the left-hand integral.

Comment: The better problem would be $$\int_e^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^p\ln(x)}$$ or even $$\int_e^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x(\ln(x))^p}$$ which are still both divergent for $p\le1$. In both cases there is an obvious primitive for $p=1$ so you can see the divergence directly and $p<1$ follows by comparison.

Answer (score -1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int x^{\alpha}\,\dd x & = {x^{\alpha + 1} \over \alpha + 1}
\\[3mm]
\int x^{\alpha}\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x & =
{x^{\alpha + 1}\ln\pars{x} \over \alpha + 1} -
{x^{\alpha + 1} \over \pars{\alpha + 1}^{2}}
\\[3mm]
\int {\ln\pars{x} \over x^{p}}\,\dd x & =
{x^{1 - p}\ln\pars{x} \over 1 - p} -
{x^{1 - p} \over \pars{1 - p}^{2}}
\end{align}

In order to avoid the divergence when $x \to \infty$, it's clear that $p$ must be $> 1$.

Comment: Can you provide a source for the second integral please?